# Find a function that plays the same role as distance function?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

If $E$ is a manifold , then the distance is smooth outside $E$. For a compact set whose capacity is zero, can we find a function that plays the same role as the distance function? I.e., can we find some $f$ such that $f(x)=0$ on $E$, $f(x)>0$ for $x\notin E$, and $f$ is smooth outside $E$?

Comment: Please make sure my edit(s) share the same meaning as your intended question.

Comment: What's capacity?

Comment: the newtonian capacity